# Nothing happens when I run 'npm start' command for react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an Android app using React Native, it was going good but for once I run 'npm start' command for running my app on emulator but now its not showing any progress or any error. Here is my command prompt. I'll really appreciate if someone can help me in this

```
E:\SaviourApp>npm start

SaviourApp@0.1.0 start E:\SaviourApp
react-native-scripts start

11:51:38: Starting packager...
```

Here is my package.json file,

```js
{
  "name": "SaviourApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Here it is @Roy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app on an Android emulator, use `npm run android`

Comment: No I am developing expo app not that one which creates two seperate android, ios directories.

Comment: If you have exp client (command line tool installed), you can run `exp android ` to run it on a simulator or use `exp start` and then scan the QR code generated with the expo app installed on your android to run on your android device

Comment: Also you can still run `npm run android` even without the two separate directories.

Comment: Ok let me try it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Basit You're welcome. Also make sure you're in the correct directory

Comment: PS E:\SaviourApp> exp start
exp : The term 'exp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ exp start
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (exp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: It means you don't have the exp command line tool installed. Use `npm install exp --global` to fix that and then run `exp init` inside your project directory. Alternatively use `npm run android`

Answer (score -1):

just try to use expo to start the app:

```
expo start
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30755048)

Answer (score -2):

Use yarn instead of npm, it's fast. Install yarn from [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable) .
Then in your directory run:

```
yarn
yarn run android
```

This will start the expo app in the emulator normally.

Also, **clear** the data & cache of expo app in the emulator.